# SHA256 from 7z file not matching FFMPEG download SHA

Tags: ffmpeg, sha256, sha

I downloaded this: https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-release-full.7z but the SHA256 which appears when right-clicking at the downloaded folder is not the same as it is shown at the link. Is this a legit file?

Comment: They match for me. The SHA265 is for the 7z file, not a folder.

Comment: Yes yes excuse me (I'm a noob). It is a 7z file. But when I right click on windows and select SHA256, it does not match the one with the link.

Comment: This the  SHA256 I'm getting:31C416F60493E78C4FCF97345C20345C2AA8672024F567DC04DB02636FDF56FB

Comment: This is the SHA256 on the site where I d/w the file: SHA256: fc7f82a9fe87ef2c58634fd9e2f9c8eb42bc4a02ea7baad45f7113b468a7b08d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You downloaded `ffmpeg-git-full.7z` instead of `ffmpeg-release-full.7z`:

| file | SHA256 (as of writing this answer) |
| --- | --- |
| `ffmpeg-git-full.7z` | `31c416f60493e78c4fcf97345c20345c2aa8672024f567dc04db02636fdf56fb` |
| `ffmpeg-release-full.7z` | `fc7f82a9fe87ef2c58634fd9e2f9c8eb42bc4a02ea7baad45f7113b468a7b08d` |

Think of it as a good mistake: users should use the git version instead of the so-called release anyway. (Releases are always outdated and are intended for distributors and those needing to stay within a certain API version. Releases are not considered to be more stable.)

Comment: Silly me! Yes it is resolved. Thank you. As I said, noob here, haha.